# What can cause kopen to hang?

Tags: kernel, aix, truss

I have the following line from an AIX truss I ran:

```
kopen("path/to/file", O_WRONLY|O_CREAT|O_NSHARE|O_DSYNC|O_LARGEFILE,S_IRUSR|S_IWUSR|S_IRGRP|S_IROTH) (sleeping...)
```

I'm assuming the `sleeping...` means we are waiting here for an extended period of time (after 10 minutes I kill it). What would cause this to hang? The only thing I can think of is that the file is locked but then would it hang or just return some error code?

Comment: Is this file on a network file system (e.g. NFS, SMB), or is it a special file (like character-device, block-device, socket or pipe)?

Comment: The file is on an NFS mount